# Include total of all products for all warehouses using GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query to get the sum quantity of each product in each warehouse :

```sql
SELECT 
    warehouse, product, SUM(quantity)
FROM
    inventory
GROUP BY warehouse, product
```

This is my current result :

```
    warehouse       product 
    San Fransisco   iPhone  260
    San Fransisco   Samsung 300
    San Jose        iPhone  300
    San Jose        Samsung 350
```

I want to include the total of products for each warehouse.
This is my expected output :

```
    warehouse       product 
    San Fransisco   iPhone  260
    San Fransisco   Samsung 300
    San Fransisco   Total   560
    San Jose        iPhone  300
    San Jose        Samsung 350
    San Jose        Total   650
    All warehouses  Total   1210
```

Comment: Take a look at [GROUPING SETS()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#group-by-grouping-sets--) or `ROLLUP`.

Answer (score 5):

One method uses `grouping sets`:

```
select warehouse, product, sum(quantity)
from inventory
group by grouping sets ( (warehouse, product), (warehouse), () );
```

Given that:you have no `NULL` values in the keys you can use `coalesce()` to get totals:

```
select coalesce(warehouse, 'Total') as warehouse,
       (case when warehouse is not null
             then coalesce(product, 'Total')
        end) as product,
       sum(quantity)
from inventory
group by grouping sets ( (warehouse, product), (warehouse), () );
```

The `product` is tricky, because sometimes it is `NULL`, sometimes `Total`, and sometimes the `product`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(warehouse,'All warehouses') AS warehouse
    , ISNULL(product, 'Total') AS product, SUM(quantity) AS quantity
FROM
    inventory
GROUP BY ROLLUP (warehouse , product);
```